# Python re.sub only match first occurrence

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I am trying to escape double quotes in a string in preparation for it to be loaded by json.loads. The code below is an attempt to figure out how to get it right.

```
import re

one = '"caption":"This caption should not match nor have any double quotes escaped","'
two = '"caption":"This caption "should have "the duobles quotes" in the caption escaped"","'

print re.sub('("caption":".*?)"(.*?",")', r'\1\"\2', one)
print re.sub('("caption":".*?)"(.*?",")', r'\1\"\2', two)
```

This is the current output.

```
"caption":"This caption should not match nor have any double quotes escaped","
"caption":"This caption \"should have "the duobles quotes" in the caption escaped"","
```

The problem is that only the first double quote in the second string gets escaped. I realize that there is an error in my regex, which is not really my strong suit. I've read through tons of threads here and spent a good amount of time on google to no avail.

Please note that the actual string I am working with is ~10 000 characters long and have multiple occurrences of both types of caption strings in it.

Comment: Python's `re` flavor is extremely basic; can you use the [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) package instead?  If not, you'll have to use program logic in addition to (or instead of) regexes.  Also, I think you've got an extra `"` at the end of your examples.

Comment: What about using `replace` in `raw` string to remove all `"` and split by `:` then generate `dictionary/json`

Comment: @AlanMoore Sure, I'll install regex tomorrow and give it a try. I fixed the output to match the input.

Comment: @SIslam The real string is a javascript array with a messy mix of what Python interprets as dicts and lists. The values is then a mix of strings, ints and floats. JSON require double quotes so removing them doesn't make any sense to me. All I need is to escape any double quotes inside the captions.

Comment: @AlanMoore There is nothing wrong with python's regex. It does everything except recursion out of the box: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines

Comment: @binarysubstrate: I didn't say the `re` module was bad, but it's missing a lot of features compared to other popular flavors.  There's good discussion about it [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-python.html).  Unrestricted lookbehind is the feature that makes [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33859417/20938) possible.

Comment: Cool, I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try `re.sub` as below-

```
one = '"caption":"This caption should not match nor have any double quotes escaped","'
two = '"caption":"This caption "should have "the duobles quotes" in the caption escaped"","'
result= re.sub(r"""(?<!^)(?<!:)(")(?!$)(?!:)""",r'\\\1',two)
print result
```

Output-

```
"caption":"This caption \"should have \"the duobles quotes\" in the caption escaped\"\","
```

LIVE [<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/iN6jV6/1)

**Regex explanation**

Just grab all the quotes that are not at line start/end, not before or after first `:` then replace them with prep-ended backslash (i.e.`\"`)

Comment: This escapes one double quote too many. The result should be:
"caption":"This caption \"should have \"the duobles quotes\" in the caption escaped\"","

Comment: Ok just `re.sub(r'''\\"\\"''',r'\\""',result)`

Comment: I ended up with this:
(?<!^)(?<!,|:|{)(")(?!$)(?!:|,"|})

Works perfect with boolean, int and string values. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> one = '"caption":"This caption should not match nor have any double quotes escaped","'
>>> two = '"caption":"This caption "should have "the duobles quotes" in the caption escaped"","'
>>> match = re.match(r"(\"caption\"\:\")(.*)(\",\")", two)
>>> midstr = match.group(2).replace('"', u'\u005C"')
>>> newstr = "".join([match.group(1), midstr, match.group(3)])
>>> print newstr
"caption":"This caption \"should have \"the duobles quotes\" in the caption escaped\"","
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

expression = """
(             # Capturing group 1
[\w ]         # The quote should be preceeded by a word char or space.
)             # End group

(")           # Capturing group 2: match a quote character.

(             # Capturing group 3
[^,:]         # Quote shuold not be followed by a comma or colon.
)             # End group
"""
pattern = re.compile(expression, re.VERBOSE)

result = pattern.sub(r'\1\"\2', one)
print(result)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hT1mI3/2)
Updatd with bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the [regex package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) installed (as discussed in the comments), this should work:

```
result = regex.sub(r'(?<="caption":".*)"(?=.*",")', r'\"', subject)
```

As you can see, the regex is the same as yours except I changed your capturing groups to lookarounds.  Since those parts of the string are no longer being consumed, there's no need to plug them back into the new string, so the replacement is just `\"`.

I can't speak to the efficiency of this regex because I don't know anything about the surrounding text.  If the target strings are on their own lines, you should be fine as long as you don't specify DOTALL mode.  But the safest approach would be to extract the strings first and process them in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

```
# fourth parameter is the position; following will remove 1st occurrence of "so"
sent = 'we are having so so much of fun'
re.sub("so",'', sent, 1)
```